# Pass Parameter From client side Node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am having a basic doubt here, which i can't make it. I have to pass two variables to server side .What i did was

Client Side

```
$("#send").click(function () {
    var getUsrName = $("#text").val();
    var getPass = $("#pass").val();
    $.post('/connect', {
        usr: getUsrName,
        pass: getPass
    });
});
```

Server Side

```
app.post('/connect', function (req, res) {
    console.log("req.body : ",req.body.usr)
});
```

Instead of request.body, I used req.params and req.query. But none of them are working. Its showing undefined.

Thanks

Comment: Do you have these lines : " var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
app.use(bodyParser.json());
 app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));" in app.js ??

Comment: show us your route and app.js

Answer (score 0):

What you're sending to the server is the payload. Just try to console log the whole request coming from the client console.log(req)
from there you will see what you have and again try to console.log(req.payload)

Thanks.

Comment: `req.payload` is not an Express thing.